# Shift elements in the iOS simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, tableview

Maybe this is silly question but I can't fix it. In StoryBoard it looks OK
[image]

But in simulator it looks:
[image]

And no matter how I shifted the TableView up it still looks the same. And it's not just this one time when I put like PickerView in the simulator it looked shifted. 
May have some setting in the inspector who is responsible for this, or what is the problem?

Comment: have you try     `if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeBottom;` ?

Comment: Check the autoResizingMask of that view

Comment: @Konstantin - didn't work

Comment: what about     `self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = YES;
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
    
    self.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;`

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO` in your `UIViewController`